# Issue with storing coordinates as geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm facing an issue regarding storing coordinates as geo_point. My goal is to add documents to ElasticSearch through a Logstash pipeline which I receive in JSON format. Omitting most of the fields the JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "text": "hello",
    "location": {
    "lat": "42.5064128",
    "lon": "1.52069438894224"
    }
}
```

Since I'm new to the ELK stack I've created a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

/etc/logstash/conf.d/mycompany-tweet-demo.conf:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 10000
        codec => "json"
    }
}

filter {    
    mutate {
        # this "works", however the location in no way matches the coordinates when displayed via tile map in Kibana
        #add_field => { "mylocation" => 52 }
        #add_field => { "mylocation" => 8 }

        # this yields "illegal latitude value [268.76953125] for mylocation"
        add_field => { "mylocation" => 51.9 }
        add_field => { "mylocation" => 7.9 }

        # this yields "illegal latitude value [269.1322946548462] for mylocation" for the demo JSON
        #add_field => { "mylocation" => "%{[location][lat]}" }
        #add_field => { "mylocation" => "%{[location][lon]}" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "mycompany-tweet-demo"
        document_type => "tweet"

        template => "/etc/logstash/templates/mycompany-demo-template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

/etc/logstash/templates/mycompany-demo-template.json:

```
{
    "template": "mycompany-*",
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "properties": {
                "mylocation" : {
                    "type" : "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

~/one.json:

```
{"text":"hello","location":{"lat":"42.5064128","lon":"1.52069438894224"}}
```

cat ~/one.json | nc localhost 10000

```
[2017-01-13T17:41:38,504][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"mycompany-tweet-demo", :_type=>"tweet", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-01-13T16:41:38.458Z 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 %{message}], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"mycompany-tweet-demo", "_type"=>"tweet", "_id"=>"AVmYtLvEovM5deO5CNpA", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"illegal latitude value [269.1322946548462] for mylocation"}}}}}
```

Based on the documentation of [geo_point](http://doodle.com/poll/95mnb449we8z4dsw) and some posts on stackoverflow I've read, I'd expect my example with values between 0 and 90 to work. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, what you need to do is this:

```
    add_field => { "[mylocation][lat]" => "%{[location][lat]}" }
    add_field => { "[mylocation][lon]" => "%{[location][lon]}" }
```

Comment: Thanks! We tried this at some point but that must've been before we had actually configured `mylocation` as `geo_point`.